# As a French PhD student in the US, what can I do to get the US citizenship as quickly as possible?

Tags: usa, citizenship, french-citizens

I (French citizen) started a PhD in computer science in the US one year and a half ago: what can I do to get the US citizenship as quickly as possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several options:

1. Marry a US citizen. Once the US government is satisfied that your marriage is not a sham marriage (i.e.: you didn't get married **just** for the immigration benefits) - you'll get a green card (permanent residency). After three years as permanent resident married to a US citizen, you can apply for US citizenship.
2. Get a green card on your own. Either through an employer (EB1/EB2 process) or because you're such a distinguish scholar that the US would want to keep you (EB1 self sponsored process). After 5 years as a permanent resident you can apply for US citizenship.
3. Have a congressman introduce legislation to the US Congress to grant you a citizenship. Once the bill passes and is signed into law by the President - you'll become a US citizen.
4. Join the US military. After 4 (IIRC...) years in the military, as long as you're not dishonorably discharged, you can apply for US citizenship.

Comment: Don't forget the chance to win it in the Greencard lottery.

Comment: Hmm @littleadv... in the #1 option, the 3 years as a permanent resident, are **in addition** to the 2 years of being a "conditional" permanent residency since it's thru a marriage... isn't? What I'm trying to say is that to become a US Citizen one will pretty much always have to wait at least 5 years, no? Unless you are military (4 yrs) or get a bill thru congress (infinite yrs... ) ;)

Comment: @CesarDV no, the 2 years "conditional" are overlapping with the 3 years you have to be married to a US citizen.

Comment: Thanks, I went with option 2, self-sponsored process. FYI, once you get the green card: [What shall one do after receiving a green card?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/12414/164) ; [I have received the green card: what should I keep track of to be prepared to apply for naturalization in five years?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/10923/164)