# Green card, how to get it?

Tags: usa, greencard

I'm an Italian who has been living in UK for more than one year now, in some year (I don't know how many) I hope i will manage how to find a job in the states (since it is my "ultimate dream"). I heard that the green card is necessary to work there.

My question is:

How to get this green card?
How much does it cost?
Any other useful information would be helpful.

Comment: I could have sworn this question had been asked here before, but I can't find it. A good place to start learning about green cards is [from the USCIS](http://www.uscis.gov/greencard).

Comment: Try for a Diversity Visa, or find a company to sponsor you for an H-1B. Both are lotteries. The DV will get you a green card, while the H-1B makes you eligible to apply for a green card (permanent residency) after several years.

Comment: It should be noted that the green card denotes *permanent residence,* which is not the only way for a foreigner to work legally in the United States.  There are many more or less temporary options.  When you say "find a job" do you mean a seasonal job or longer-term employment? Would you want to move to the US permanently or just for a few years?

Comment: I would like to move there permanently. So i guess i need a permanent job there, however i don't know exactly how it works there for foreigners to find a job. But since I'm not an american i suppose it's not that easy to find a permanent job there. So i was wondering what could i do to make my life easier.

Comment: FYI [As a French PhD student in the US, what can I do to get the US citizenship as quickly as possible?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/360/164)

Answer (score 2):

1)  Marry an American.

2)  Have your child marry an American and then apply for you.

3)  Diversity lottery.  This is quite a longshot.

4)  H1-B work visa assuming you are in a field in demand.  You might be able to convert that to a green card.  Again, a lottery but with much better odds.

There are also investor visas but they're for people funding a business, not for employees.  The amount you must invest is beyond the means of the average person.

Comment: I thought it coulb be possible buy one of those... I guess i was wrong

Comment: @lukkio The investor visa is basically bought except you invest the money rather than give it to the government.  Given the $500k pricetag it's obviously not applicable to you.

Comment: The child has to be over 21 to apply for you, so this route can be very time consuming.

Comment: @phoog Not really because they'll need to be 18 to marry the American in the first place and it takes a while before they can apply for their parents.  I doubt the age 21 limit ever comes into play in such a situation.  The only way I can see it being meaningful is A+B have C.  They split, B marries D (American) while C is a minor.  When C turns 21 they can apply for A.

Comment: I don't have any child. So pay was a kind of my first option.

Comment: But considering the price... i give up on that.

Comment: Many US states allow minors to marry with parental permission.