# I have received the green card: what should I keep track of to be prepared to apply for naturalization in five years?

Tags: usa, citizenship

I have received the green card: what should I keep track of to be prepared to apply for naturalization in five years?

For example, one needs to be able to provide the accurate travel history of the past five years. What else should I keep track of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend that you get your hands on a copy of the [N-400, Application for Naturalization](https://www.uscis.gov/n-400).  This will indicate the things you will want to keep track of.  Among other things, it asks about the following

- Employment and school
- Time spent outside the US
- Marital history
- Children
- US voting history (a few municipalities allow noncitizens to vote)
- Tax history
- Organizational memberships

The last is a particularly broad question:

> Have you EVER been a member of, involved in, or in any way associated with, any organization, fund, foundation, party, club, society, or similar group in the United States or in any other location in the world?