# How do I know how many days I spent outside the USA in the past 5 years?

Tags: usa, citizenship, greencard

I travel outside the country for family and business, I would like to know how I can find out how long I stayed. I can't keep track on the passport stamps. Is there a website that can tell you how long you stayed outside the country?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no one website. You should keep track of your travel, the best way is to keep a spreadsheet where you keep track of every exit and entry and destinations visited. You'll need to provide the dates of travel and the destinations on your N400, so it would help you a lot to write it down as you're traveling.

If you hadn't done it, you'll have to retroactively reconstruct this information. Use the passport stamps, but these are not very reliable - in many countries you don't get stamps, or you can get stamp in one country while visiting multiple (e.g.: in Europe). So you'll probably want to go through your flight and hotel reservations, expense reports, and any other record you may have.

Answer (score 1):

One can submit a FOIA (Freedom of Information Act) request to the US CBP for entry and exit records. However, it'll miss the exits to Mexico via land (and perhaps via sea, I don't know).

FOIA screenshot:

[image]

FYI:

- [What's the approx. processing time of online FOIA requests for entry/exit to prepare for N400 (Application for Naturalization)? Days, weeks, months?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/22456/164)
- [What is the difference between "Information Regarding Entry and Exit" and "travel history" for the U.S. Customs and Border Protection?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/168429/1810)
- [If I submit a FOIA request to the CBP for entry and exit records, does it show travel between US states and US territories?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/176059/1810)
- [Where can one view the time of the day of one's entries and exit to/from the United States?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/169496/1810)